# Can I show video on my website if I upload it to different hosting that I would own?

Tags: html, web, html5-video, hosting

we have website, name it X. We can't store video directly in it in order to load it with HTML5  tag. Is it possible to buy a new domain & hosting to store that video there and load into website X with code like this?

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" ><source src="https://www.newdomain. com/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

Embed option doesn't suit as there are visible controls, no loop and autoplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like images, which can be hosted elsewhere, you can embed videos that are hosted anywhere, provided that the URL is publicly accessible.

Comment: Do I need a domain for my new hosting? I mean, how I will get URL of the uploaded video? I just need hosting FTP to upload and somehow get a link to it?. However, visiting the domain would show nothing, as I need it only to get the link to the video.

Comment: Many hosting companies provide a free subdomain from the hosting companies own domain.  You could also use a subdomain of your main domain.  You could also get a subdomain that you are likely to control longer term from a dynamic dns company. There shouldn't be a need to purchase a domain name if you don't expect the user to ever see it.